# Fade-to certain opacity using dojo

Tags: dojo, fadein

I'm using dojo toolkit. (version 1.6)
I'm unable to stop the fading effect at certain opacity (say 0.5)
Here is the code I'm using

```
 var fadeArgs = {node: "disabled_div", duration: 3000};
 dojo.style("disabled_div", "opacity", "0"); 
 dojo.fadeIn(fadeArgs).play();
```

But the above code is fading the element's opacity from 0 to 1.
My requirement is to stop fading effect at 0.5 opacity.

Please help me out

Thanks in advance!
SuryaPavan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try like this:

```
    var w = dojo.animateProperty({
    node:"disabled_div",
            duration: 3000,
    properties: {
        opacity: 0     
    },
    onAnimate:function(a){
        if(a.opacity <= .5)
        w.stop();
    }
})
```

OR

```
dojo.style("disabled_div", "opacity", "1"); 

var fadeArgs = {node: "disabled_div", duration: 3000,onAnimate:function(o){

 if(o.opacity <= .5){
   anim.stop()
 }
}};
anim =  dojo.fadeOut(fadeArgs);
anim.play();
```

Comment: Hi RajKamal,Thanks for the reply. I have tried using ur code. and in the above code I have posted, I just replaced 'fadeArgs' with ur 'w'. But could'nt get the solution. Its fading till opacity 1 :( Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use fadeTo from the DojoX extensions

Comment: Could you add a short example for the asker. :)